# Tilemap looks small

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, tile

I am new to tilemap on cocos2d-x c++ and I created a tilemap on Tiled 50x50 tiles with 32 x 32 pixels per tile. And I added to the screen.

However, what I see on the screen is not what I excepted. The tiles look really small on a 480 x 320 screen.

[My Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezE4G.jpg)

It looks like 3.2 x 3.2 pixels per tile instead of 32 x 32. Anyone had any idea why this would happen?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely a bug of tilemap in cocos2d-x due to the change of resolution. You can try scaling the map up like this:

```
_map = cocos2d::experimental::TMXTiledMap::create("tile.tmx");
auto director = Director::getInstance();
_map->setScale(director->getContentScaleFactor());
```